# How to combine multiples sum and dates from mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Im trying to generate data for a graph but everytime i attempt to do it it basically just gives me 1 sum. For the graph i need the date and the value.

This is my current code:

```
$chart_data = "";
    $earnings_query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(R.rate) as ratess,R.date FROM reports R WHERE R.pid = '$publisher_id' AND R.status = '2'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($earnings_query) > 0)
    {

        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($earnings_query))
        {
            $date = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($row['date']));
            $chart_data.= '{"date": "'.$date.'", "value": '.$earnings_total['tot'].'},';
        }
    }

    echo $chart_data;
```

the output is `{"date": "12/31/1969", "value": },` but i should be getting daily data all the way back from June 6.

Thanks to all the comments below, the code below solves my problem.

$earnings_query = mysql_query("SELECT SUM(R.rate) as ratess, R.date FROM reports R WHERE R.pid = '$publisher_id' AND R.status = '2' GROUP BY date(R.date)");
if (mysql_num_rows($earnings_query) > 0)
{

```
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($earnings_query))
{
    $date = date("m/d/Y",strtotime($row['date']));
    $chart_data.= '{"date": "'.$date.'", "value": '.$row['ratess'].'},';
}
```

}

echo $chart_data;

Comment: 12/31/1969 is because the value you are reading is 0: Unix time is expressed in seconds since that date. This can be for a number of reasons - maybe the field you are reading is actually 0, or incompatible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `group by` clause:

```
SELECT SUM(R.rate) as ratess, R.date
FROM reports R
WHERE R.pid = '$publisher_id' AND R.status = '2'
GROUP BY R.date;
```

Without the `group by`, your query is an aggregation query that runs over the entire set of data.  The result (without a `group by`) is always going to be one row.

If your column called `date` has a time component, then you might want to use the `date()` function:

```
SELECT SUM(R.rate) as ratess, date(R.date) as date
FROM reports R
WHERE R.pid = '$publisher_id' AND R.status = '2'
GROUP BY date(R.date);
```

Comment: Appreciate this, fixed the date problem but why is the value 4 only? it doesn't update its 4 for all dates.

Comment: also there is data before i started saving datetime so they have the defaults of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 as date how can i exclude those?

Comment: @user2002220 . . . You can use a `where` clause to eliminate dates that you don't want.  As for why you are getting certain values, that is because of your data.  You can set up a SQL Fiddle, if you like.

Comment: ok im good on the where to eliminate but still dont see why it onyl show 4 as the value. Like i have multiple records for a date and it should add the sum of the rates and that should be shown as the value for the day.

Comment: Add `and r.date <> '0000-00-00 00:00:00'` to the `where` clause.

Answer (score 0):

Add a GROUP BY date to your SQL command.

```
SELECT SUM(R.rate) as ratess, R.date
FROM reports R
WHERE R.pid = '$publisher_id' AND R.status = '2'
GROUP BY R.date
```

This will sum for each date in the range, whereas you were summing for all dates and then selecting the first date. If the date field isn't just a date, but also includes time information, you'll want to use DATE(R.date) instead.